# Python Post doesnt post anything

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to make a program that will connect on a website using this code:

```
import requests

url = "https://website/cours/login/index.php"


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Mobile Safari/537.36"

}



brack = requests.post(url,headers = headers, data={"username":"e19****","password":"0****"})



content = brack.content
print(content)
```

the thing is that when im posting, nothing happens, like if I just did a GET. There's no error when I run (200 OK).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the API definition, a POST request may not return a content. Since you're getting a 200 response. Most probably there's a `json` object that was returned with your POST request.

Try this:

```
import requests

url = "https://website/cours/login/index.php"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Mobile Safari/537.36"

}


response = requests.post(url,headers=headers, 
           data={"username":"e19****","password":"0****"})


print(response.json())
```

Usually, if the POST request is expected to give a real-time/streaming ("instant") response to provide/return some data or content, then you might get an session/job ID where you can poll/fetch the completed job at a later time.

These tutorial might be helpful:

- https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api/
- https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-an-api-with-python/
- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp